# Can I include a password in my rsync call?

Tags: rsync

I use rsync to update my static website. I currently `cd` to the local website directory, and run the `rsync` command, and then enter the password in the next line. I've saved my `rsync` call into a text snippet (such that `_rs` just expands to my call). Is there way to use something like a `-p` flag at the end and include the password too?

My call looks like this:

`rsync -avzh -e ssh * foo@foo.org:"/home/foo/public_html/"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of option is use public/private key pair, see [How to auto rsync with ssh passwordless](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=238672)

Or you can try use [Expect](http://debaan.blogspot.de/2007/09/simple-expect-ssh-example.html)

Answer (score 3):

Answering this with a direct answer to the question, may be useful in less secure scenarios.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set PASSPH "123456"
send_user "\n"
stty -echo

spawn rsync -apv -e ssh "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/charliechaplin/test/" "charly@chaplin.com:/project/htdocs/site/"
expect "password:"
send "$PASSPH\n"
expect "#"
```