# How to answer the rsync password prompt using IPC::Run?

Tags: perl, ipc

I do not have Expect and I don't get it to work on my machine. 
I do not use an ssh key pair for rsync, but will supply a password (no, the password is not stored in the script or somewhere else - it's just a program that gets the password from somewhere and has to insert it).
I'm using cygwin on Windows x64

I tried to handle it using [`IPC::Run`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run) but I failed. Somehow, the password prompt seems to behave other than a normal prompt.

This works:

Reproduction script ask.pl to generate a prompt:

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "enter something:\n";
my $answer = <STDIN>;
print "your answer was: $answer\n";
exit(0);
```

Reproduction script to answer ask.pl's prmot:

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::Run qw( start pump finish timeout );

my @cmd = ( "perl", "ask.pl" );

my $in = "ask something:\n";
my $out;
my $h = start( \@cmd, \$in, \$out, timeout(5) );

pump $h until $in =~ /something:/;
$in = "1234\n";
finish $h or die "app returned $?";

print "done";
```

This does not work:

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::Run qw( start pump finish timeout );

my @cmd = ( 'rsync', '-avr', 'user@host:/som/path/in/filesystem', '/target/folder' );

my $in = "password:\n";
my $out;
my $h = start( \@cmd, \$in, \$out, timeout(5) );

pump $h until $in =~ /password:/;
$in = "secret-password-here\n";
finish $h or die "app returned $?";

print "$out";
print "done";
```

So how do I provide the password to rsync?

I looked at other threads (provide password to SCP / SSH etc.) but the solution is either using Expcect or a key pair. But I cannot use Expect or the key pair.

Comment: How? Using expect or a key pair of course (sorry).

Comment: You may be able to run `rsync` on top of `plink` which can get the password as a command line argument.

Comment: @AKHolland I can't use Expect and I cannot use the key-pair method. I'm looking for another way. I guess it's somehow possible to "simply" write the password to the prompt.

Comment: @capfan Then this might not be possible. Maybe if you went into a bit more detail about *why* you've decided you can't use those tools, they might be solvable problems.

Comment: This seems similar to [a problem I had](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480056/feeding-input-to-an-interactive-command-line-application) which was due to another type of reads being used to get passwords.

Comment: @Qtax: right, I don't know how it is done on Windows, but on Linux/Unix systems, SSH reads the password directly from the process TTY.

Comment: The solution of Qtax looks promising. On Linux or cygwinm, there seems to be a solution using expect: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029140/can-i-include-a-password-in-my-rsync-call/15177797#15177797

Comment: @capfan: on Linux you have [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/module/Net::OpenSSH) that takes care of everything (establishing the SSH connection and running rsync on top) for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 changes you need to make.

1. You have to use a [pseudo tty](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run#PSEUDO-TERMINALS) to capture the password prompt.
2. To make it work in IPC::Run you have to [run bash first](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=38228) then the command you want.
3. You need to match `$out` with `/password:/` not `$in`.

Here's the script, hope it helps:

```perl
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::Run qw( start pump finish timeout );

my @cmd = ('bash', '-c', 'rsync -avr user@host:/som/path/in/filesystem /target/folder');

my $in;
my $out;
my $h = start \@cmd, '<pty<', \$in, '>pty>', \$out, timeout(5);

pump $h until $out =~ /password:/;
$in = "secret-password-here\n";
finish $h or die "app returned $?";

print "$out";
print "done";
```